# Does my phone need an Internet connection to install apps from Google Play?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-store

First of all please excuse me if this too basic. I'm very new to the Android field. I just bought an Android phone. Now I'm looking to install some apps on my phone.

After some researching I found that Google Play is the place to get all the apps. So I logged in with my Gmail account on the Google Play website and installed `Talking Tom` app through the browser. It's showing under my "My Android Apps"

[image: Talking Tom]

But it still hasn't been added in my phone. At first I thought it might take some time for it to get downloaded to my phone. But now it's been more than 3 hours and still it isn't listed under my apps in the phone.

This makes me wonder if this is not how Google Play works. If it's not, then what is the appropriate way to get an app to download to my phone.

PS : My phone does not have an internet data plan and is not connected to the internet. I'm beginning to think maybe that is the reason it's not been downloaded yet. But does it not work something like how SMS's work where you don't need the phone to be connected to the internet?

Comment: Cellular data is a different technology than SMS, and they don't work the same way. So if you don't have a data plan, you won't be able to use the Internet unless you connect via WiFi. All Android phones have WiFi built in (as far as I know, anyway). Go into the "Settings" app and look for the WiFi settings. If you can connect to a WiFi network, Talking Tom Cat should be downloaded sooner or later, as long as you set up your Google account on the phone.

Comment: So that means my phone needs to be connected to the internet, right? And yes I do have WiFi option in my phone but my PC does not have a WiFi router....

Comment: Yes, your phone needs to be connected to the internet to install the app. And you most likely had an internet connection when you configured your Google account on your device (otherwise you could not have triggered the installation of the app on Google Play). // @TreborRude You might want to add that as an answer (feel free to include parts of my comment along to make facts clear ;) so aspirin might accept it once finding out it solved the issue.

Comment: @Izzy That makes it clear. Also, I access Google account through the PC and not the phone. So there was never a moment where I accessed anything related to internet through my phone.

Comment: Then I wonder how you could select your device when installing from the PC -- as that would require your device being registered with your account, which again requires it to have an internet connection (at least until registration / account setup (on the device) is finished.

Comment: Oh yes..you're right...I did connect it once using my calling balance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do need an internet connection to install apps. It doesn't matter if you install them from your phone or from a PC.

In order to connect to the internet through a USB connected to your computer, you can use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.littlelan.ReverseTether.Paid&hl=en), but it requires you to have a rooted device.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I've been searching a lot on `tethering` and also found that `reverse tethering` is what I'm looking at. Unfortunately, many solutions require to root my phone which I don't want to as it will void the warranty. +1 btw and accepting

Comment: Actually the link to the app that you provided looks like doesn't require rooting, but without my phone being able to access the net, I won't be in a position to install it :(

Comment: You can always unroot the device and regain the warranty.

Comment: Go to a public WiFi area and install that app first. You should find one really easily.

Comment: Hmm..that's an option. I'll see what I can do. Thanks again.